# Linq query output does not match with Sql query output

Tags: sql, linq

```
Repository.Calls
    .Count(call => call.OutcomeActionDate.Value >= fourWeeksStartDate && 
                   call.OutcomeActionDate.Value < threeWeeksStartDate && 
                   call.UserId == user.UserId);
```

Above query gives me output 1 and the sql query:

```
select * 
from calls 
where userid = 1006 and
      outcomeactiondate >= '2013-08-19' and
      OutcomeActionDate < '2013-08-26'
```

gives me the output 15.

The output 15 is correct. I am not sure why is the linq query giving me incorrect value ?
All the parameter values used in select query are same as passed in the linq query.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to look at the SQL been generated by your code and checked it is what you expect?

Comment: What are the values of fourWeeksStartDate, threeWeeksStartDate, user.UserId. Most likely they are different from the ones in the sql query.

Comment: Date used must be in date format, some times we have time and we use the datetime that creates problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Date` part of filtered dates:

```
Calls.Count(call => call.OutcomeActionDate.Value >= fourWeeksStartDate.Date &&
                    call.OutcomeActionDate.Value < threeWeeksStartDate.Date &&
                    call.UserId == user.UserId);
```